# Link without jumping to top of page

Tags: hyperlink

I have the following link on my website:

```
<a href="/pages/getting-started-step-2-of-5" title="Next Step">
    <span style="text-decoration: underline;">Next Step</span>
</a>
```

It works fine, however, would it be possible to change it so that when the link is clicked and the new page is opened it does not automatically scroll to the top of the page? i.e. the new page is in the same position as the previous page was?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you read about [Internal links.](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/text/internallinks.html)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, is it possible to set the link so that when the new page opens the id attribute is in the middle of the page instead of at the top?

Comment: Or even so that when the new page opens? It automatically opens half way down?

Comment: Not sure if that is possible, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using HTML tags.

You should be using anchors.

You can have named anchors to jump to.

```
<a name ="jumphere">here</a>
```

You can jump to named anchors by using there names after a #.

```
http://somedns.com/index.php#jumphere
```

[more info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp)

Named anchors are no longer supported in HTML5 - use id instead in HTML5 pages.

Comment: It is I know, but still works. You really should be using something else - you are right.